# How to fix jlabel problem with numbers when number is above 100?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

i made some simple game like cookie clicker. It works as it should, but problem is that when number of points goes above 100 i can't see them properly. I will leave whole code bellow. I made it a bit complicated for a reason, but only issue right now i had is with jLabel...

So i hope someone will help me.

```
package javaapplication17;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.*;

public class JavaApplication17 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBP prozor = new DBP();
        prozor.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prozor.setVisible(true);
        prozor.setLocation(600, 250);
        prozor.setLayout(null);


    }

}
class DBP extends JFrame{
        private JLabel oznaka;
        private int brojac;
        private boolean upgraded1;
        private boolean upgraded2;
        private boolean upgraded3;
        private boolean isup1;
        private boolean isup2;
        private boolean isup3;

        public DBP(){
            setTitle("Cookie Clicker");
            setSize(800, 480);
            setLayout (new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 20));



            oznaka = new JLabel("No points!");

            add(oznaka);
            JButton dugme = new JButton("Click");
            add(dugme);





            JButton upgrade = new JButton("Buy first upgrade!");
            upgrade.setBounds(317, 50, 150, 50);
            add(upgrade);
            upgrade.setVisible(false);

            JButton upgrade2 = new JButton("Buy second upgrade!");
            upgrade2.setBounds(317, 100, 150, 50);
            add(upgrade2);
            upgrade2.setVisible(false);

            JButton upgrade3 = new JButton("Buy third upgrade!");
            upgrade3.setBounds(317, 150, 150, 50);
            add(upgrade3);
            upgrade3.setVisible(false);



            dugme.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                brojac++;

                if(upgraded1){
                    isup1 = true;
                }

                if(upgraded2){
                    isup2 = true;
                }

                if(upgraded3){
                    isup3 = true;
                }

                if (isup1){
                    brojac += -1;
                }

                if(isup1){
                    brojac += 2;
                }

                if(isup3){
                    brojac += 4;
                }

                oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                if (brojac >= 5 && !upgraded1){
                    upgrade.setVisible(true);

                }
                if(brojac >= 10 && !upgraded2){
                    upgrade2.setVisible(true);
                    if (isup1){
                        upgrade2.setBounds(317, 50, 150, 50);
                    }
                }
                if(brojac >= 50 && !upgraded3){
                    upgrade3.setVisible(true);
                    if (isup1 && isup2){
                        upgrade3.setBounds(317, 50, 150, 50);
                        }else if (isup1 && !isup2){
                            upgrade3.setBounds(317, 100, 150, 50);
                            }else {
                                upgrade3.setBounds(317, 150, 150, 50);
                    }
                }
               }
            });


            upgrade.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    upgraded1 = true;
                    isup1 = true;
                    upgrade.setVisible(false);
                    brojac -= 5;
                    oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                 }
            });

            upgrade2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    upgraded2 = true;
                    isup2 = true;
                    upgrade2.setVisible(false);
                    brojac -= 10;
                    oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                 }
            });

            upgrade3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    upgraded3 = true;
                    isup3 = true;
                    upgrade3.setVisible(false);
                    brojac -= 50;
                    oznaka.setText("Points " + brojac);
                 }
            });

}
}
```

Comment: What happens if you give sufficient width?

Comment: One simple solution is to give larger initial text with spaces: `oznaka = new JLabel("No points!                    ");`

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for that good suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either set a preferred size:

```
oznaka.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
```

OR

Set the initial text large enough (space appended):

```
oznaka = new JLabel("No points!       ");
```

Comment: *"Either set a preferred size:"* See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  **(Yes.)**